# How to download newer data today and yesterday from FTP?

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp, winscp

I want download newer data from my FTP by name file with variable yesterday and today, structure file like this

> Daily_(City)_(yyyymmdd).xlsx

I have tried this code

daily.bat

```
winscp.exe /console /script=daily.txt
```

daily.txt

```
::: Begin set date

for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/-. " %%i in ('date /t') do (call :set_date %%i %%j %%k %%l)
goto :end_set_date

:set_date
if "%1:~0,1%" gtr "9" shift
for /f "skip=1 tokens=2-4 delims=(-)" %%m in ('echo,^|date') do (set %%m=%1&set %%n=%2&set %%o=%3)
goto :eof

:end_set_date
::: End set date

set /a today=%dd%
set /a yesterday=%dd%-1

@echo off
open Reg_8@192.168.8.1  
get -neweronly "/Reg8/Kota/2016/Daily/Daily_Makassar_%yy%%mm%%today%.xlsx" "D:\FTP\Makassar\2016\daily"
get -neweronly "/Reg8/Kota/2016/Daily/Daily_Makassar_%yy%%mm%%yesterday%.xlsx" "D:\FTP\Makassar\2016\daily"
pause
```

If I run this script not happen...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are combining Windows and WinSCP commands in a single file. That's not possible. Start with reading the [guide to automating file transfers from FTP server or SFTP server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation).

And your script is too complicated, because you do not make use of the [WinSCP `%TIMESTAMP%` syntax](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#timestamp).

---

A simple way (`daily.txt`):

```
open ftp://user:mypassword@ftp.example.com/
get -neweronly "/Reg8/Kota/2016/Daily/Daily_Makassar_%TIMESTAMP#yyyymmdd%.xlsx" "D:\FTP\Makassar\2016\daily"
get -neweronly "/Reg8/Kota/2016/Daily/Daily_Makassar_%TIMESTAMP-1D#yyyymmdd%.xlsx" "D:\FTP\Makassar\2016\daily"
```

(only this, discard all the other code from your `daily.txt`)

The `%TIMESTAMP#yyyymmdd%` will resolve to `20161006`.
The `%TIMESTAMP-1D#yyyymmdd%` will resolve to `20161005` (as of 2016-10-06).

You need WinSCP 5.9 and newer for this.

---

Also in general, you should call the [`winscp.com`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/executables) from a batch file, not the `winscp.exe /console`.